# Custom loss for huggingface Trainer for sequences

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, floating-point, torch

I have a dilemma, for the following custom loss I got this error:
code:

```
class CustomTrainer(Trainer):
  def compute_loss(self, model, inputs, return_outputs=False):
    use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
    device = torch.device("cuda" if use_cuda else "cpu")
    
    # forward pass
    outputs = model(**inputs)
    logits = outputs.get("logits")
   

    # logits: (batch_size, sequence_length, num_classes), reshape it to (batch_size*sequence_length, num_classes)
    predictions = logits.view(-1, model.config.num_labels)
    # shape: (batch_size*sequence_length)
    predictions = predictions.argmax(dim=-1)

    labels = inputs.get("labels").to(device)
    labels =  labels.view(-1) 

    labels = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.float)
    predictions = torch.tensor(predictions, dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=True)

    loss = loss_fct(predictions, labels)


    return (loss, outputs) if return_outputs else loss
```

Error:

> IndexError: Target 17 is out of bounds.

When I remove these lines of converting dtype:

```
#labels = torch.tensor(labels, dtype=torch.float)
#predictions = torch.tensor(predictions, dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=True)
```

I got this error:

> RuntimeError: Expected floating point type for target with class
> probabilities, got Long

Comment: in which line you are having this error? `IndexError: Target 17 is out of bounds.`